# GZip archiver for log files

Tags: ruby, file-system, file, logging, compression

It compiles, works well, solves my problem of zipping old or big log files and removes them from a hard drive. However, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9190590/692020), I would like to know what was wrong with the code.

```
Dir.foreach(FileUtils.pwd()) do |f|
    if f.end_with?('log')
        File.open(f) do |file|
            if File.size(f) > MAX_FILE_SIZE
                puts f
                puts file.ctime
                puts file.mtime

                # zipping the file
                orig = f
                Zlib::GzipWriter.open('arch_log.gz') do |gz|
                  gz.mtime = File.mtime(orig)
                  gz.orig_name = orig
                  gz.write IO.binread(orig)
                  puts "File has been archived"
                end

                #deleting the file
                begin
                  File.delete(f)
                  puts "File has been deleted"
                rescue Exception => e
                  puts "File #{f} can not be deleted"
                  puts "       Error #{e.message}"                
                  puts "======= Please remove file manually =========="
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Ruby's indentation style is usually 2 spaces, just as a minor heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My proposal, please see also the comments in the code.

```
require 'zlib'
MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024 #One KB

#Use a glob to get all log-files
Dir["#{Dir.pwd}/*.log"].each do |f|
  #skip file, if file is small
  next unless File.size(f) > MAX_FILE_SIZE
  #Make a one line info
  puts "#{f}: #{File.size(f)/1024}KB, created #{File.ctime(f)} modified #{File.mtime(f)} "

  # zipping the file - each log in a file
  Zlib::GzipWriter.open("arch_#{File.basename(f)}.gz") do |gz|
    gz.mtime = File.mtime(f)
    gz.orig_name = File.basename(f) #filename without path
    #File.read should be fine for log files. Or is there a reason for IO.binread
    gz.write File.read(f) 
    puts "File #{f} has been archived"
  end

  #deleting the file
  begin
    #~ File.delete(f)
    puts "File #{f} has been deleted"
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "File #{f} can not be deleted"
    puts "       Error #{e.message}"                
    puts "======= Please remove file manually =========="
  end
end
```

Remark:

This solution creates one gz-file per log file. Your old solution created one `arch_log.gz`. If there were two log-files, the 2nd would overwrite the 1st.

Comment: defintely sorry I didn't put require and global variables, thanks for a good answer

Comment: @DanielMyasnikov if this answered the question (made a good suggestion?) then you should mark it as the selected answer.

Comment: @knut, no there were no reason for IO.binread, I just got if from Ruby Doc library web-site (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/GzipWriter.html)